# Redis password lost after reboot system

Tags: .net, redis

I want to set up a password on Redis, for this I ran a command and configured by below command.

```
> config set requirepass <password>
```

It works fine at all, Redis needs authentication but whenever Server is restart or kill the Redis and Re-open it. The password reset to default (i.e. Blank)

```
> config get requirepass
```

Kindly, any quick help will be appreciated.
Note: I am using Windows

Answer (score 2):

From the doc [here](https://redis.io/topics/config):

> Note that modifying the configuration on the fly has no effects on the
>   redis.conf file so at the next restart of Redis the old configuration
>   will be used instead.

You should update the config file instead for it to persist.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. Do you mean,  I will configure the password in Redis config "requirepass MyPassword" 
and then I have to call redis-server as 
> "redis-server redis.config" command

Comment: Yep if you specify the config to use when you start the server that has that line, that should do the trick

Comment: I see - Thanks  :D

Comment: Alternatively, use the same as in the original question, and then issue `CONFIG REWRITE` to persist the changes to the configuration file.